# Add module path to netbeans package

Tags: java, selenium, netbeans, package

I have a java application that uses selenium and the phantomjs webdriver.  I access the phantomjs executable by absolute path:

```
//              *** Phantomjs driver ***
                System.setProperty("phantomjs.binary.path", 
                  "/Users/myuser/Desktop/Desktop Archive/Crashplan/Gecko/phantomjs");
                driver = new PhantomJSDriver();
```

I want to include the phantomjs executable as part of my jar.  How would I add this module as part of my package?

Comment: add phantomjs.exe to your project inside a folder and the refer to that path using System.setProperty("phantomjs.binary.path", 
                  "./yourfolde/phantomjs");

Comment: I created a new folder under my project and called it "drivers"  I added phantomjs to this directory.  Then System.setProperty("phantomjs.binary.path", "./drivers/phantomjs");  It does not find phantomjs.

Comment: YOU need to write `System.setProperty("phantomjs.binary.path", "./drivers/phantomjs.exe");`

Comment: This is on a mac.  There is no .exe.

Comment: Oh..okay  my bad...

Comment: Your original answer was correct.  I had a bad phantomjs module in my drivers directory.  When I fixed this, your answer was spot on.  Thank you.

Comment: Now it runs fine in netbeans.  Where can I put it so it will be copied into the jar and executed correctly from there?